# Generate OpenApi Spec from Typescript Project

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, swagger, openapi

We are running our typescript services on aws-lambda using the plain `ApiGatewayProxyEvent` instead of any `express` or other middlewares. Each route in the service has it's own function definition in `AWS Lambda`.

We would like to have a code-first approach on creating our OpenApi spec similar to what `SpringFox` does for Spring, but without using any runtime dependency on a framework.

In our current PoC we use `typescript-rest` and `typescript-rest-swagger` to annotate the controllers and then call `swaggerGen -c ./swaggerConfig.json -p ./tsconfig.json`. This provides us with the correct OpenApi Specification. 
However, when we run the actual function in our environment we get the following exception:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'typescript-ioc' in '/(...)/node_modules/typescript-rest/dist/server'
 @ ./node_modules/typescript-rest/dist/server/server.js 105:18-72
 @ ./node_modules/typescript-rest/dist/typescript-rest.js
 @ ./src/controllers/myController.ts
 @ ./src/handlers/myHandler.ts
 @ ./src/lambda.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/typescript-rest/dist/server/server.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'typescript-ioc/es6' in '(...)/node_modules/typescript-rest/dist/server'
 @ ./node_modules/typescript-rest/dist/server/server.js 105:18-72
 @ ./node_modules/typescript-rest/dist/typescript-rest.js
 @ ./src/controllers/myController.ts
 @ ./src/handlers/myHandler.ts
 @ ./src/lambda.ts
```

Our assumption is, that this is since `typescript-rest` is an `express` plugin and thus needs the service to run on `express`. 
Is there any way to create the spec without having the runtime dependencies? 
If not, are there other tools that allow the code-first approach?

Comment: would you be able to provide sample code (or link to the documentation you've used) about how you've managed to generate the OpenAPI specification. My team is facing similar issue and would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @pafede2 unfortunately, i do not have access to those projects anymore. Checking the `typescript-rest` module is the only hint i can give

Comment: Unfortunately, No. We ended up using a spec-first approach instead which turned out to be the better solution overall.